# Is there a way to extract only one column from all the 30 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 30 dataframes, but from each of these dataframes i just want one column from them. Each of these dataframes contain stock prices OHLC, Adj Close and volumes. I want to extract only one column from 30 dataframes i.e. "Adj Close"

How do i do that without making the code lengthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3...df30]

#if need Series
out = [df['Adj Close'] for df in dfs]
#if need one column DataFrames
#out = [df[['Adj Close']] for df in dfs]
```

Or loop:

```
out = []
for df in dfs:
    #if need Series
    out.append(df['Adj Close']) 
    #if need one column DataFrames
    out.append(df[['Adj Close']])
```

Last if need one big DataFrame with each column for each Series:

```
df_big = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: This command is actually appending all the close values below one another. How do we make separate columns of Adj Close in a new dataframe?

Comment: @the_learning_child - Do you think `df_big = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True, axis=1)` ?

Comment: yes, i forgot ```axis=1``` Now its giving the correct output. Thank you